# C# Threading inside for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, nested

I want the for loop to complete before I print the result, in:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            (new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
                {
                    if (TimeTakingMethod())
                    {
                        ++nResult;
                    }
                })).Start();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Count = " + nResult);
```

but Console.WriteLine will not wait for those threads to finish because printing is done on the main thread.

If I change it to:

```
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    (new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
                    {
                        if (TimeTakingMethod())
                        {
                            ++nResult;
                        }
                    })).Start();
                }
            });
        t.Start();
        t.Join();
        Console.WriteLine("Count = " + nResult);
```

it will still not solve the problem because the nested threads will not be waited for.

Any simple solution to this? Thanks for going through this.

Comment: What is the point of using threads like this? you are just waiting until it finishes anyway...

Comment: Obscure logic? I'd suggest you to explain what are you doing and why? nested threads for no obvious reason

Comment: Idos and Saleem, the wait is because the result should be printed only after the loop processing. I used threading there because each iteration of the loop is time taking. The explanation I've given in the question column is a much simplified version of a complex task so this question may make it look like the program doesn't need multithreading.
Crashmstr, I agree, thanks for it. The following written on that page helped, along with other answers given on this page: 

List<Thread> threads=new List<Thread>(); 
//Add your threads to this collection 
threads.WaitAll();

Comment: TVOHM and YottaGinneh, Thanks for the answers, it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the created threads to control them, I used a List.

```
        int nResult = 0;
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {

            Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
            {
                if (TimeTakingMethod())
                {
                    ++nResult;
                }
            });
            thread.Start();
            threads.Add(thread);
        }

        foreach (Thread thread in threads)
            thread.Join();

        Console.WriteLine("Count = " + nResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of how you could do this:

```
int result = 0;
Task.WaitAll(Enumerable.Range(0, 5)
    .Select(index => Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        // Do thread things...
        Interlocked.Increment(ref result);
    })).ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The two important things to note are `Task.WaitAll` which will cause the program to wait for all tasks to complete before moving on to the WriteLine call.

Also `Interlocked.Increment` will allow you to safely increment result from any thread.